# How to raise several incremented CollectionType

Tags: forms, symfony4, entity-relationship

I have an Entity "Habilitation" that contains an ArrayCollection of an Entity "Droits", which contains an ArrayCollection of an Entity "DetailsDroits".

I have a FormType "HabilitationType", which has a CollectionType for "Droits", which itself contains a CollectionType for "DetailsDroits".

Except that my form does not go back in my page, the forms children are absent and I do not find where (according to the documentation) I was wrong.

Entities

```
//Entity Habilitation
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Droits", mappedBy="habilitation", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $droits;
--------------
//Entity Droits
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Habilitation", inversedBy="droits")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $habilitation;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\DetailsDroits", mappedBy="droit", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 */
private $details;
--------------
//Entity DetailsDroits
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Droits", inversedBy="details")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $droit;
```

FormType

```
//HabilitationType
use App\Form\DroitsType; -> my IDE keeps it gray, as if my method did not use it
$builder[...]
    ->add('droits', CollectionType::class,
        [
            'entry_type' => DroitsType::class,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'entry_options' => [
                 'label' => false,
             ],
         ])[...]
--------------
//DroitsType
use App\Form\DetailsDroitsType; -> my IDE keeps it gray, as if my method did not use it
$builder
    ->add('details', CollectionType::class,
        [
            'entry_type' => DetailsDroitsType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                 'label' => false,
            ],
        ]);
--------------
//DroitsType
$builder->add('libelle', TextType::class, ['label' => false])
        ->add('description', TextType::class, ['label' => false])
        ->add('codeLdap', TextType::class, ['label' => false])
        ->add('isAdmin', CheckboxType::class, ['label' => false]);
```

dump() of HabilitationType -> doesn't contain a child form for the "droits" label

[image: a busy cat]

Can we increment CollectionType in CollectionType? Or not? Or did I understand the documentation to do it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I believe "increment" is the wrong word. "nest" may be better. and tbh I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: regarding your grayed out `use` clauses: it's probably gray because you don't need `use` clauses, if the class is in the same namespace and same directory (at least in symfony with a properly configured composer you don't), so you can safely remove those lines.

Comment: final comment: have you checked, that `Habilitation::getDroits()` actually returns the collection of `Droit`s? (you might need to call `->toArray()` on the persistent collection)

Comment: In my "droit" field, I had to have the field "liste" and the child form "droitDetails". Off I don't have it. I have nothing.